# How to wait till delete function is complete on firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following piece of code in my app.

```
let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
db.collection("users").document(currentUserId).updateData(["Token": FieldValue.delete()])
Auth.auth().signOut()
```

The signout completes before the delete and hence the delete is not accomplished on firestore. How do I wait to attempt sign out till the delete function is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the closure:

```
db.collection("users").document(currentUserId).updateData(["Token": FieldValue.delete()]) {
    err in
    if err == nil {
       do {
           try Auth.auth().signOut()
       } catch let error {
           // Sign out failed with error, do something
       }
    } else {
       // Update database error, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: First I get the error to add 'try' in front on Auth. When I do that, I get the error 'Extra argument in call'

Comment: @FCDeveloper: why do `try`? Depending on your case, you can just ignore the `err`, or check `if err == nil { // Sign out here } else { // Have error, do something here }`

Comment: With no try on signout, I get the following error: "Call can throw but is not marked with 'try'"

Comment: Ok, that's another question not included in your OP. Anyway, I updated my answer with error handler. Hope that helps.